# getElementById is returning null when assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript

`getElementById` is returning null when assigned to a variable.

```
var element = document.getElementById("ul1");
var newelement = document.createElement("li");
newelement.innerHTML = "New";
element.appendChild(newelement);
```

Comment: have you placed your script tag  after `ul1`

Comment: You either don't have an element with that ID, or it's not available ***yet*** !

Answer (score 0):

When you put your javascript in the `head` of the document it will load (and block the loading of the `body`) before any other element on the page.

A quick example of what you're **actually** doing would be this:

```
<!-- script runs before element creation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var element = document.getElementById('ul1');
</script>
<!-- this is after execution, where JS could not find the element but only now is the element actually created -->
<ul id="ul1"></ul>
```

To solve this issue, you can do a few things

- place the `<script>` tag below the element you want to target
- place the `<script>` tag just above the closing `</body>` tag)
- use `window.onload = function() { ... }` to make sure the page is loaded before doing anything.

Then the `ul` element will exist and you will be able to append your LI :)

Comment: In a comment to Mathews' answer you said: "it's about the DOM not being loaded" How can you know that? OP's code snippet doesn't provide that information.

Comment: My personal favorite is to put my script(s) in a (few) function(s) in a linked file, then just call them right above `</body>`. It's cleaner and takes advantage of caching.

Comment: @Teemu because the only reasons `document.getElementById` can't find your element is if either 1)`The ID literally does not exist (typo'd somwhere or removed)` or 2)`DOM isn't loaded`. The former is a very basic debug problem, the latter is simply not knowing that's a thing.

Comment: @abluejelly Nope, there is [one more reason](http://jsfiddle.net/ob5Lq47q/) : ).

Comment: @Teemu that would be the 1 option- literally does not exist. You're trying to be a smartass, and you're not doing a very good job of it :^)

Comment: @abluejelly You didn't took a careful look at the code. The element exists, but it's not appended to the DOM, hence DOM getters can't find it (`querySelector` could find it). Looking at OP's code, it's a possible case. What comes to smartasses, well, you know ...

Comment: @Teemu except it doesn't exist. `document.createElement` does not append to the `document`, it's merely a constructor. Thus, the element still does not exist inside `document`, which is where `document.getElementById` naturally searches. We're still in the "literally does not exist" state, and obviously so since there isn't an `element.createElement` function to make you think it'll auto-append it as a child of `document`. I stand by you're trying to be a smartass, and not succeeding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97310/discussion-between-abluejelly-and-teemu).